# Easting and northing conversion into lat and long gives wrong information python

Tags: python, pyproj

This is my easting and northing
315846.356,5808849.713

```
p2 = Proj(proj="utm",zone='55H')
x,y=315846.356 ,5808849.713
lat,long=p2(x,y,inverse=True)
```

I got Longitude  144.29314340365048 and Lattitude 52.39886078782927
The lat is correct but long information is not 
The coordinates are from MELBOURNE, AUSTRALIA
zone information is obtained from google earth

Comment: What's the correct longitude?

Comment: here something completly wrong, positive latitude for australia with 144 degree? Check lat,lon from wikipedia and calculate utm with that zone.

Comment: @AndreasMuller Sorry thats was wrong i have made some edits  the longitude was 144.29314340365048 and the lattitude was wrong

Comment: What happens if you try to use a negative y value (*-1), i am pretty sure proj uses only the zone  number and therefor values south the equator are negativ.

Comment: tried thislat,long=p2(x,y,inverse=True)

Comment: but gives -52.39886078782927
the correct one is -37.849226127116296

Comment: is there any way to specify zone letter on  p2 = Proj(proj="utm",zone='55')

Comment: Try using something like "+proj=utm +zone=55H, +south +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"

Comment: If my answer does what you want, do not forget to check it as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that it is not `lat, long=p2(...)` but `long, lat=p2(...)`. But it looks like you simply forget to set the initial EPSG code [you need](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/gda94-mga-zone-55/). See

```
>>> p2 = Proj(init="epsg:28355", proj="utm", zone=55)
>>> lon, lat = p2(x,y,inverse=True)
>>> lon
144.9069089150736
>>> lat
-37.84921977801404
```